# Javascript: How can I turn a String into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have a string formatted as below:

```
{"title":"XYZ","id":"123"} {"title":"NPS","id":"124"}{"title":"LMW","id":"125"}
```

I am trying to convert this into an array by storing it in a variable and splitting it as such:

```
let prodInfo = "{"title":"XYZ","id":"123"} {"title":"NPS","id":"124"}{"title":"LMW","id":"125"}";
```

I then split this variable as in:

```
   let infoArry =  prodInfo.split("}");
   console.log(infoArry);
```

The results I get after this is:
[image]

The issue is when I loop through this array to access titles separately, I get it as undefined.

Any recommendations would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have control over the input string? If you make a couple of amendments it could be made in to valid JSON which can be parsed in a single call to `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Yes I can change the string format, @Ro

Comment: Since you have the ability to change it, change it to: `[{"title":"XYZ","id":"123"},{"title":"NPS","id":"124"},{"title":"LMW","id":"125"}]` then you can just use JSON.parse(str)

Answer (score 3):

Given that you state in the comments under the question that you are able to change the input string format, I would strongly suggest you convert it to valid JSON. Then you can simply call `JSON.parse()` and work with the resulting array as needed. Try this:

```js
var input = '[{"title":"XYZ","id":"123"},{"title":"NPS","id":"124"},{"title":"LMW","id":"125"}]';
var output = JSON.parse(input);

output.forEach(obj => console.log(obj.title)); // just an example
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const input = '{"title":"XYZ","id":"123"} {"title":"NPS","id":"124"}{"title":"LMW","id":"125"}';

const objects = input.split("}").filter(element => !!element).map(element => JSON.parse(element + "}"));;


objects.forEach(object => console.log(object["title"]));
```